# Печать на принтере меток через браузер

Tags: node.js, angular

Имеется принтер меток. И хотелось бы, чтобы пользователи моего сайта на Angular могли печатать тоже на принтере меток без установки левых программ.

Так как я до этого использовал QZ Tray, который хорошо работает, но проблема в том, что пользователям сложно пользьзоваться или установить QZ. Так же пробовал напечатать с помощью window.print в JS, но проблема в том, что мой принтер не отображается как принтер меток и нет возможности печать любые размеры, только стандартные А0/А1/А3/A4/A5.

Так-же пробовал использовать USBWeb api, но моего принтера он не находит.

Остается разве что написать отдельный сервер на Node js или Java spring. Бэкэнд у меня написан на Node js, но как понимаю для принтера придется писать второй бэкэнд который будет работать на компе пользователя.

Собственно просьба в том, чтобы направить меня на путь истинный, так как я совсем запутался.

Comment: Вроде как `QZ Tray` это [open source решение](https://github.com/qzind/tray), я бы попробовал покопаться в исходниках и упростить установку и использование для своих пользователей. Если я правильно понял суть проблемы, то пользователям в любом случае придется что-то "левое" у себя устанавливать, зачем тогда самому все писать, когда есть готовые решения.